# Running uinput code on DM368 board

Tags: ubuntu, embedded

I am using DM368 TI board. I want to send keystrokes to gstplayer in ubuntu 10.10 For that purpose i used uinput function in C code. My code works properly on console but not on the hardware. I even generated uinput.o file on the board. Please give suitable suggestion

Here's my code :

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
/* Globals */
int uinp_fd;
struct uinput_user_dev uinp;       // uInput device structure
struct input_event event; // Input device structure
/* Setup the uinput device */
int setup_uinput_device()
{
    // Temporary variable
    int i=0;
    // Open the input device
    uinp_fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (uinp_fd<0)
    {
        printf("Unable to open /dev/uinput\n");
        //die("error: open");   
        return -1;
    }

    // Setup the uinput device
    if(ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY)<0)
        printf("unable to write");
    if(ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REL)<0)
        printf("unable to write");
    if(ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_X)<0)
        printf("unable to write");
    if(ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_Y)<0)
        printf("unable to write");
    for (i=0; i < 256; i++) {
        ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, i);
    }
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MOUSE);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TOUCH);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MOUSE);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_LEFT);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_MIDDLE);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_RIGHT);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_FORWARD);
    //ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_BACK);


    memset(&uinp,0,sizeof(uinp)); // Intialize the uInput device to NULL
    snprintf(uinp.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "uinput-sample");
    uinp.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
    uinp.id.vendor  = 0x1;
    uinp.id.product = 0x1;
    uinp.id.version = 1;

    /* Create input device into input sub-system */
    if(write(uinp_fd, &uinp, sizeof(uinp))< 0)
        printf("Unable to write UINPUT device.");


    if (ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE)< 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to create UINPUT device.");
        //die("error: ioctl");
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;

}
void send_click_events( )
{
    // Move pointer to (0,0) location
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    event.type = EV_REL;
    event.code = REL_X;
    event.value = 100;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_REL;
    event.code = REL_Y;
    event.value = 100;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_SYN;
    event.code = SYN_REPORT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    // Report BUTTON CLICK - PRESS event
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    event.type = EV_KEY;
    event.code = BTN_LEFT;
    event.value = 1;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_SYN;
    event.code = SYN_REPORT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    // Report BUTTON CLICK - RELEASE event
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    event.type = EV_KEY;
    event.code = BTN_LEFT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_SYN;
    event.code = SYN_REPORT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
}
void send_a_button()
{
    // Report BUTTON CLICK - PRESS event
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    event.type = EV_KEY;
    event.code = KEY_ENTER;
    event.value = 1;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_SYN;
    event.code = SYN_REPORT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    // Report BUTTON CLICK - RELEASE event
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    gettimeofday(&event.time, NULL);
    event.type = EV_KEY;
    event.code = KEY_ENTER;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
    event.type = EV_SYN;
    event.code = SYN_REPORT;
    event.value = 0;
    write(uinp_fd, &event, sizeof(event));
}
/* This function will open the uInput device. Please make
   sure that you have inserted the uinput.ko into kernel. */
int main()
{
    // Return an error if device not found.
    if (setup_uinput_device() < 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to find uinput device\n");
        return -1;
    }
    sleep(1);

    send_a_button();           // Send a "A" key
    // send_click_events();       // Send mouse event
    /* Destroy the input device */
    ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
    /* Close the UINPUT device */
    close(uinp_fd);
}
```

Comment: How does it fail on the hardware?

Comment: First of all you didn't describe the error or what exactly your problem is. There could be something wrong with your cross compilation environment or your kernel for the DM368 board may have no uinput module